# obtener informacion de el cliente por medio de asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Localmente me da la información correcta, pero cuando publico el código me aparece la información del servidor:

```
public string Usuario()
{
    String el = Environment.UserName;
    return el;
}

public string Nombre()
{
    string hostname2 = Environment.MachineName;
    return hostname2;
}
public string serialnumber()
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher MOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_BaseBoard");
    string serial = "";
    foreach (ManagementObject getserial in MOS.Get())
    {
        serial = getserial["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    }
    return serial;
}
```

Comment: Sencillamente el código adquiere la información de tu servidor dónde está publicado el sitio, por ende cuando realizas la prueba funciona en tu PC. Además, ¿Te has puesto a pensar que sería de los sitios web que puedan obtener información de tu PC a través de un explorador?, sería una gran falla de seguridad.

Comment: si lo pensé, pero si son computadoras controladas quiero decir que no son personales,

Answer (score 0):

No puedes obtener dicha información. Tanto UserName como MachineName solo te dan la información del usuario y la máquina en la cual la aplicación se está ejecutando.